# TikZ, refer to intersection with x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

In this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel,calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=-0.1, ymax=1.5,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xlabel=$Q$,ylabel=$H$,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot[name path=pump,blue,domain=0:1.5] {-0.5*x^2+1};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load1] {0.5*x^2+0.4*x+0.5};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load2] {2*x^2+1.6*x+0.5};

\path [name intersections={of=load1 and pump}]; 
\coordinate [label= $A$ ] (OP1) at (intersection-1);
\path [name intersections={of=load2 and pump}]; 
\coordinate [label= $B$ ] (OP2) at (intersection-1);
%\path [name intersections={of=pump and axis}]; 
%\coordinate [label= $C$ ] (OP3) at (intersection-1);

\end{axis}

\foreach \point in {OP1,OP2}
  \fill [red] (\point) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(adapted from [a more complex example](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=997ug3)) I would like to create a coordinate `OP3` at the intersection between the line named `pump` and the x-axis, so that I can use `\fill [red] (\point) circle (2pt)` also there.

The commented lines

```
%\path [name intersections={of=pump and axis}]; 
%\coordinate [label= $C$ ] (OP3) at (intersection-1);
```

represent a failed attempt. Neither `{of=pump and xaxis}` or `{of=pump x-axis}` work.

How to refer to the intersection between `pump` and the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name x axis, for example with

```
x axis line style={name path=<name>}, % <--- in axis preamble
```

and then you can write:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                babel,backgrounds,
                calc,
                intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
x axis line style={name path=xaxis}, % <---
xmin=0, xmax=2, 
ymin=-0.1, ymax=1.5,
xlabel=$Q$,ylabel=$H$,
ticks=none,
            ]
\addplot[name path=pump,blue,domain=0:1.5] {-0.5*x^2+1};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load1] {0.5*x^2+0.4*x+0.5};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load2] {2*x^2+1.6*x+0.5};

\path [name intersections={of=load1 and pump, by=a}] 
        node[dot, label= $A$] at (a)  {} ;
\path [name intersections={of=load2 and pump, by=b}] 
        node[dot, label= $B$] at (b) {} ;
\path [name intersections={of=pump and xaxis, by=c}] 
        node[dot, label= $C$] at (c) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the name to the axis line, there is no need to redraw it (which among other things requires you to know its precise location). This can by accomplished by adding

```
every inner x axis line/.append style={name path=x-axis}
```

BTW, `fillbetween` loads `intersections`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} %<-consider adding
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,red,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=3pt}]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=-0.1, ymax=1.5,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xlabel=$Q$,ylabel=$H$,
ticks=none,
every inner x axis line/.append style={name path=x-axis}
]
\addplot[name path=pump,blue,domain=0:1.5] {-0.5*x^2+1};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load1] {0.5*x^2+0.4*x+0.5};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load2] {2*x^2+1.6*x+0.5};

\path [name intersections={of=load1 and pump}]
 (intersection-1) coordinate [bullet,label= $A$ ] (OP1)
 [name intersections={of=load2 and pump}]
 (intersection-1) coordinate [bullet,label= $B$ ] (OP2) 
 [name intersections={of=pump and x-axis}]
  (intersection-1)  coordinate [bullet,label= $C$] (OP3);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]