# Using pgfplotspointgetcoordinates together with fillbetween command

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm curios with following strange behavior of my code (see MNWE below). If the command for filling area between function is added, than the coordinates **A** and **B** are changed. It is weird for me, because I am using the command `pgfplotspointgetcoordinates` for obtaining the correct coordinates for point-1 and point-2. What is going on?

[image: correct graph without fill command]

The problematic code is:

```
  \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] 
    fill between[of=gx and fx,soft clip={domain=-1:1}];
```

And the figure is changed too much. The graph curves are changed and the coordinates for point A and B is touched.

I also see that the point coordinates are influenced by:

```
  enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
  enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
```

[image: wrong graph with active fill command]

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,scale=0.5, 
    every node/.style={transform shape}
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
      domain = -2:2,
      restrict y to domain=0:4,
      grid = major,   % both
      grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
      major grid style={dashed, line width=.2pt, draw=gray!40},
      minor tick num=5,
      clip = true,
      clip mode=individual,
      axis x line = middle, 
      x axis line style={name path=xaxis}, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574555/tikz-refer-to-intersection-with-x-axis
      axis y line = middle,
      xlabel={\(x\)},
      ylabel={\(y\)},
      enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
      enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
    ]
    
      \addplot[
        name path global=fx,
        color=Gold3, samples=20, 
        smooth, ultra thick, 
        unbounded coords=jump, 
        no markers
      ]  gnuplot{2/(1+x^2)}; 
      
      \addplot[
        name path global=gx,
        color=Coral4, samples=20, 
        smooth, ultra thick, 
        unbounded coords=jump, 
        no markers
      ] gnuplot{x^2};  

      % fill area bounded by two curves
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38461/
      \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] 
        fill between[of=gx and fx,soft clip={domain=-1:1}];

      \path [name intersections={of=fx and gx, name=point}];
      \node (prusecikA) [left,  font=\scriptsize] 
        at (point-1) {
        % -------------------------------------------------------------
        % using '\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates' stores the (axis)
        % coordinates of e.g. the coordinate (point-2) in
        % 'data point', which then can be called by '\pgfkeysvalueof'
          \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(point-1)}
          \(A=[
              \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
              \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
          ]\)
        };
      \node (prusecikB) [right,  font=\scriptsize] 
        at (point-2) {
          \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(point-2)}
          \(B=[
              \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
              \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
          ]\)
        };
     

      \draw[dashed] (-1,0) -- (point-1);
      \draw[dashed] (+1,0) -- (point-2);
      \node[below left] at (0,0) {\(0\)};
      \node[left, Gold3] at (1.5,2.3) {\(f(x) = \frac{2}{1-x^2}\)};
      \node[right, Coral4] at (-2,4) {\(g(x) = x^2\)};
      \fill [black] (point-1) circle (1mm);
      \fill [black] (point-2) circle (1mm);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the "line thickness" stuff is an already reported bug <https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/138>. But that the shown coordinates change when `fillbetween` is used is new to me. This seems as an unknown bug. Are you willing to create a bug report in the tracker?

Comment: @StefanPinnow: Yes, If you think, that it is a bug. To be honest I am not familiar with bug reporting. :-(

Comment: If you have a GitHub account, just give it a try. Have a look at the template to report a bug and/or at some other bugs that are already in the tracker to get an idea how to do it. Please add a link to this question here, than I will see it and maybe I'll fine-tune it a bit if I think this is needed to make it a good/more useful bug report. (As with everything in life: There is a first time for everything :))

Comment: Could you please state if you are willing to **try** to write a bug report? If not, I would do it.

Comment: @StefanPinnow. That would be very nice of you.

Comment: For the record: The second bug has been filed in the tracker as well <https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/436>.